# How to filter list using CAML query from a custom search field?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, search, wss, caml

**Background**

I'm configuring a custom WSS application that focuses around one main list. I want to replace the top sharepoint search box with my custom search. After clicking on search I want to load a page with a webpart presenting the results (basically filtered list using CAML query). 
I'm using WSS not MOSS so I cannot just configure a search scope, and still CAML seems to give me exacly what I want.
How can I connect webpart and a custom search that not always are on the same page?

**Questions**

How can I connect webpart and a custom search that not always are on the same page?

I'm new to SharePoint programming and I have a deadline in few days :) so I will really appreciate pointing me in the right direction xD

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently posted two articles ([part 1](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2009/08/use-case-phonebook-search-no-code-required/) | [part 2](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2009/10/search-as-you-type-for-links-list/)) with very similar solution done with JavaScript. It allows you to do "search as you type" over a single list.

It is not exactly the thing you are looking for but it might help.